# angular-soundmanager2 - how to rebuild the playlist?

Tags: angularjs

This is [library](http://perminder-klair.github.io/angular-soundmanager2/doc/usage.html) I use.
For rebuilding playlist I do following:

```
angularPlayer.clearPlaylist(function () {
    angular.forEach($scope.filtered, function (value) {
                        //$scope.$apply(function () {
                            angularPlayer.addTrack(value);
                        //});

                    });
});
```

Firstly, I clear playlist by function `angularPlayer.clearPlaylist`.

After I add all tracks in loop using `angularPlayer.addTrack`.

At the end I try to play playlist:

```
 angularPlayer.play();
```

But it does now work. I checked console Chrome there are not errors.

Comment: Somebody can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried some ways and have invite solution, may be it will be useful for someone:

```
$scope.play = function (genre) {

            $timeout(function () {

                angularPlayer.stop();
                angularPlayer.setCurrentTrack(null);

                angularPlayer.clearPlaylist(function () {

                    if (genre !== undefined) {
                        $scope.filtered = filterFilter($scope.songs, {'genre': genre});

                    } else {

                        $scope.filtered = $scope.songs;
                    }

                    if (random) {
                        $scope.filtered = $filter('shuffleArray')($scope.filtered);
                    }

                    if ($scope.filtered.length == 0) {
                        console.log("No songs by genre " + genre);
                    }

                    angular.forEach($scope.filtered, function (value) {
                        angularPlayer.addTrack(value);
                    });

                    angularPlayer.play();

                });

            });
        };
```